# PADES-LTV Document timestamp verification error

Tags: pdf, timestamp, digital-signature, adobe-reader, pades

I am signing a pdf document in PADES-LTV signature format with a Document timestamp signature.

Usually, signed files are OK. Both signature and document timestamp signature is verified and everything is OK. However, sometimes the following result occurs:

When I try to open the signed document with Adobe reader version 10.1.0.534, signature is validated however Document timestamp signature can not be verified. It says: At least one signature requires validating on the top bar. When I look at the Signatures section on the left, It says: **Signer's identity is invalid because it has expired or is not yet valid.** If I try to open the signature details of the document timestamp, Adobe reader crashes. (I submitted a bug report for this issue but I have not received any response yet)

When I open the signed document with Adobe Acrobat X pro and view the details of the document timestamp signature, this value "**1970/01/01 03:00:00 +03'00'**" is displayed in the signature date field. Actually, Date field should be **Not available** since ETSI 102 778-4 V1.1.2 says: In the document timestamp dictionary Name, M, Location, Reason and contact info should not be present.

Why does the adobe reader shows this value **1970/01/01 03:00:00 +03'00'** instead of **Not Available**?

What can be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: With Adobe reader update to version 10.1.1.33, crash problem is solved however verification problem still exists.

Comment: If you still have this verification issue and look for an answer, please share a sample document to reproduce the issue.